# looping through blocks of records from csv

Tags: powershell

i have a csv where i have around ***8*** rows.

Now there are some calculation, and based on that i have to group data on 3 rows each, add and get avg of them.

e.g.

```
timestamp;user_MIN;user_MAX;user_AVERAGE;nice_MIN;nice_MAX;nice_AVERAGE;system_MIN;system_MAX;system_AVERAGE;idle_MIN;idle_MAX;idle_AVERAGE;iowait_MIN;iowait_MAX;iowait_AVERAGE;irq_MIN;irq_MAX;irq_AVERAGE;softirq_MIN;softirq_MAX;softirq_AVERAGE
1. 1600013580;0.40213333333;0.40213333333;0.40213333333;0;0;0;0.63016666667;0.63016666667;0.63016666667;98.6436;98.6436;98.6436;0.32213333333;0.32213333333;0.32213333333;0;0;0;0.0019666666667;0.0019666666667;0.0019666666667
2. 1600013640;0.3618;0.3618;0.3618;0;0;0;0.59983333333;0.59983333333;0.59983333333;98.748533333;98.748533333;98.748533333;0.29786666667;0.29786666667;0.29786666667;0;0;0;0;0;0
3. 1600013700;0.3618;0.3618;0.3618;0;0;0;0.59983333333;0.59983333333;0.59983333333;98.748533333;98.748533333;98.748533333;0.29786666667;0.29786666667;0.29786666667;0;0;0;0;0;0
4. 1600013760;0.3618;0.3618;0.3618;0;0;0;0.59983333333;0.59983333333;0.59983333333;98.748533333;98.748533333;98.748533333;0.29786666667;0.29786666667;0.29786666667;0;0;0;0;0;0
5. 1600013820;0.3618;0.3618;0.3618;0;0;0;0.59983333333;0.59983333333;0.59983333333;98.748533333;98.748533333;98.748533333;0.29786666667;0.29786666667;0.29786666667;0;0;0;0;0;0
6. 1600013880;0.3618;0.3618;0.3618;0;0;0;0.59983333333;0.59983333333;0.59983333333;98.748533333;98.748533333;98.748533333;0.29786666667;0.29786666667;0.29786666667;0;0;0;0;0;0
7. 1600013940;0.30983333333;0.30983333333;0.30983333333;0;0;0;0.46146666667;0.46146666667;0.46146666667;98.932633333;98.932633333;98.932633333;0.29803333333;0.29803333333;0.29803333333;0;0;0;0;0;0
8. 1600014000;0.30983333333;0.30983333333;0.30983333333;0;0;0;0.46146666667;0.46146666667;0.46146666667;98.932633333;98.932633333;98.932633333;0.29803333333;0.29803333333;0.29803333333;0;0;0;0;0;0
```

***Note: added row numbers for sample***

so here first block will be row number 1-3, then 4-5, and then 7-8

so for all the groups above, need to calculate sum of all rows and divide by the number of rows in the block( i.e. 3 and for the last one 2)

i have the code for calculating the sum and the  avg

```
***( given some variable names)***

$Hash = [ordered]
                foreach ($Property in $Properties) {
                    $Hash[$Property] = (($New_Extracted_Data.$Property | Measure -Sum).Sum)/$NumberOfRowsToPick

                }
```

Need to know how to divide the data in blocks.

Please need some idea on how to do this.

Below is the code is dividing my data into equal blocks, but the problem is for the last two row (i.e. 7-8) it is not considering.

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here

```
function break_csv($BlockCount)
{

$SourceDir = "C:\Script"
$InFileName = 'Server_raw_data.csv'
$InFullFileName = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath $InFileName

$BatchCount = $BlockCount

$DestDir = "C:\Script"
$OutFileName = 'LF_Batch_.csv'
$OutFullFileName = Join-Path -Path $DestDir -ChildPath $OutFileName

$CsvAsText = Get-Content -LiteralPath $InFullFileName
[array]$HeaderLine = $CsvAsText[0]
$rowcount = ($CsvAsText.Count) - 2 
$BatchSize = [int]($rowcount / $BatchCount)

$StartLine = 1

foreach ($B_Index in 1..$BatchCount)
    {
    if ($B_Index -ne 1)
        {
        $StartLine = $StartLine + $BatchSize
        $CurrentOutFullFileName = $OutFullFileName.Replace('_.', ('_{0}.' -f $B_Index))
        $HeaderLine + $CsvAsText[$StartLine..(($StartLine + $BatchSize) - 1)] | Set-Content -LiteralPath $CurrentOutFullFileName
        }
        else
        {
        $CurrentOutFullFileName = $OutFullFileName.Replace('_.', ('_{0}.' -f $B_Index))
        $HeaderLine + $CsvAsText[$StartLine..$BatchSize] | Set-Content -LiteralPath $CurrentOutFullFileName
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are the row numbers (ie. `1.`, `2.` etc) part of the actual file, or did you add them for the sample?

Comment: i have added them for sample

Answer (score 0):

Separate selection of blocks from calculating the averages by implementing the average calculation routine in its own function:

```
function Get-RowAverage
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [psobject[]]$InputObject,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string[]]$Property
  )

  # Calculate average for the selected $Property values here and return result
}
```

Now you just move your calculations into that function and divide by `$InputObject.Count`, and then pass each "block" of rows individually:

```
$allRows = Import-Csv .\path\to\input.csv

$firstBlockAvg = Get-RowAverage $allRows[0..2] -Property $Property
```

Comment: i have to code to get the avg. i wanted to know how to divide the data in blocks.

Comment: @EmptyCoder It's not at all clear from your question how and why the sample you've shown should be partitioned into 1-3, 4-5, and 7-8  (what about line 6?) - What's the intended logic?